# WiFi only works after restarting, but not shutting down from Windows

Tags: drivers, wireless, windows

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.10 dual booting on my computer.

I've tested the following behavior several times

- Boot Windows -> Restart -> Boot Ubuntu -> Wi-Fi works
- Boot Windows -> Shutdown -> Power on -> Boot Ubuntu -> Wi-Fi doesn't work

Specifically it says it can't see Wi-Fi card.
If I reboot or power off/on from Ubuntu to Ubuntu, it preserves the same behavior that it had before reboot.

If more information is needed, let me know how to get it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing this issue and I believe Windows 10 has a fast startup feature which doesn't shut down your system but instead puts your kernel in a deep hibernation state to boot faster. This unfortunately means that when you boot into ubuntu, you aren't performing a clean boot. You can try turning this off by following steps [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/). If that works, awesome! Else I'm afraid you might have to resort to restarting windows for now

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Same here. After I deactivated fast startup, Wifi works on Linux without rebooting from Windows first.